# how to render data fecthed from firebase database in react-native functional components

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm getting data from firebase databse in console that look like this. `[{ "isDonor": true, "name": "Nadi", "photo": "https://gre", "uid": "2ZE" }, { "email": "mmaz", "isDonor": true, "name": "Mz", "photo": "https://gra", "uid": "Cb" }]`
I want to create cards of each objects but how to accomplish that as data is fetched after some time?
I want to render it like this
[image]

Ihave checked other answres but they are mostly from class component.
I have tried using `useEffect` hook but couldn't implement it
here is my code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

const donorsData = [];
database()
  .ref('users')
  .orderByChild('isDonor')
  .equalTo(true)
  .once('value')
  .then((results) => {
    results.forEach((snapshot) => {
      // console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
      //   console.log(snapshot.val());
      donorsData.push(snapshot.val());
    });
    //   console.log('aft', donorsData);
  });
export default function New() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {donorsData.map((v, i) => {
        return (
          <View
            key={v.uid}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              padding: 10,
              margin: 5,
              borderRadius: 10,
            }}>
            <Text>{v.name}</Text>
            <Text>{v.email}</Text>
            <Image source={{uri: v.photo}} style={{height: 150, flex: 1}} />
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from "react-native";
import database from "@react-native-firebase/database";

export default function New() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const donorsData = [];
    database()
      .ref("users")
      .orderByChild("isDonor")
      .equalTo(true)
      .once("value")
      .then((results) => {
        results.forEach((snapshot) => {
          donorsData.push(snapshot.val());
        });
        setData(donorsData);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {data?.map((v, i) => {
        return (
          <View
            key={v.uid}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "white",
              padding: 10,
              margin: 5,
              borderRadius: 10,
            }}
          >
            <Text>{v.name}</Text>
            <Text>{v.email}</Text>
            { v.photo && <Image source={{ uri: v.photo }} style={{ height: 150, flex: 1 }} />} 
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
  },
});
```

Comment: really appreciate that. Thanks ❤️

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with the below code...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

export default function New() {

    const [donorsData, setDonorsData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const getDataHandler = async () => {
        try {
            setIsLoading(true)
            database()
              .ref('users')
              .orderByChild('isDonor')
              .equalTo(true)
              .once('value')
              .then((results) => {
                 setIsLoading(false);
                 const data = results.map((snapshot) => {
                    return snapshot.val()
                 });
                 setDonorsData([...data]);
              }).catch(err => {
                 setIsLoading(false);
              });
        } catch(err) {
            setIsLoading(false)
            console.log("error : ", err.message);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getDataHandler()
    }, []);

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {
                donorsData
                    .map((v, i) => {
                        return (
                            <View
                                key={v.uid}
                                style={{
                                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                                    padding: 10,
                                    margin: 5,
                                    borderRadius: 10,
                                }}
                           >
                               <Text>{v.name}</Text>
                               <Text>{v.email}</Text>
                               <Image source={{uri: v.photo}} style={{height: 150, flex: 1}} />
                            </View>
                        );
                    }
               )}
         </View>
  ); 
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
        padding: 8,
        backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    },
});
```

Comment: Not working. Nothing comes on screen not even ActivityIndicator and console is clear also

Comment: can you try by adding a console in the firebase document result...

Comment: also, try by adding a console in the catch block of the firebase document

Comment: got this error ` [TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...results.map...')]`

Comment: try to log the results in the then block of firebase document

Comment: I made mistake while addidng console log. This is the actual error .  ` [TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...results.map...')]`

Comment: Okay, try to log the results in the firebase document...

Comment: if i comment console in firebase doc `const data = results.map((snapshot) => {
            return snapshot.val();
            // console.log(snapshot.val());
          });
          setDonorsData([...data]);
        })` then i'm getting err `[TypeError: results.map is not a function. (In 'results.map(function (snapshot) {
                    return snapshot.val();
                  })', 'results.map' is undefined)]`

Comment: in then block console is giving result as expected

Comment: no. in then block it is giving values. in .catch block console gives error `[TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...results.map...')]`

Comment: try to log the results receiving from the firebase document in then block before map and setIsLoading(false) and check the log what you are receiving in results

Comment: ` [TypeError: results.map is not a function. (In 'results.map(function (snapshot) {
                    return snapshot.val();
                  })', 'results.map' is undefined)]`

Comment: I mean to say, add the console before the results.map add console.log(JSON.stringyigy(results)) then add setIsLoading(false) and then results.map code... in the firebase document

Comment: before `setIsLoading` it is working and result are shown in console

Comment: Yes now understand the structure of the log before mapping it...
Your issues will be resolved

Comment: I'm sorry I didnot understand what do you mean by structure

Comment: The structure means the log of results check is the results is an array?

Comment: do u mean i should run console before mapping? I'm sorry  i'm new to this

Comment: No show me the console log, i will try to help you

Comment: {"": {"age": "10", "bloodType": "O -ve", "email": ".com", "gender": "male", "isDonor": true, "location": "", "name": "Mu Az", "number": "", "photo": "https://graph..com//picture", "uid": ""}, "": {"age": "10", "bloodType": "O -ve", "email": "@.com", "gender": "male", "isDonor": true, "location": "Faisalabad", "name": "Din No", "number": "", "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com//picture", "uid": ""}}
[Fri Feb 05 2021 17:16:40.690]  LOG      [TypeError: results.map is not a function. (In 'results.map(function (snapshot) {
  return snapshot.val();
   })', 'results.map' is undefined)]

Comment: here you are getting blank keys that will overwrite the existing key in the object so you will able to get only one object from the two... how do yo have setup the data in firebase database ?

Comment: but i"m getting data above setIsLoading. in firebase i have '/users/{user_uid}/{user data}' this format

Comment: can you share the screenshot of your data in the firebase database?

Comment: Have you removed the user_id from the log you provided me previously? If yes, then try Object.keys(results).map() instead of results.map()

Comment: yes i removed some data due to charachter limit in comment section

Comment: Have a try with Object.keys(results).map() instead of results.map()

Comment: I used like this `const data = Object.keys(results).map((snapshot) => {
            return snapshot.val();
          });
          setDonorsData([...data]);
        })` 
and got this error 
`[TypeError: snapshot.val is not a function. (In 'snapshot.val()', 'snapshot.val' is undefined)]`

Comment: replace this return snapshot.val(); with return snapshot

Comment: i did and i console.log value of snapshot and i'm getting this `snap _snapshot
[Fri Feb 05 2021 17:51:47.145]  LOG      snap _ref` . Two Views did render on screen but without any data

Comment: Try with replace this return snapshot.val(); with return { ...snapshot }

Comment: it renders like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncP73.png) with this code ` return {...snapshot}` and with this code also `return snapshot;` both have same result as in picture

Comment: I run this `const data = Object.keys(results).map((snapshot) => {
            console.log('snap', snapshot);
            return snapshot;
          });` and this is the console result 
`[Fri Feb 05 2021 17:57:31.967]  LOG      snap _snapshot
[Fri Feb 05 2021 17:57:32.180]  LOG      snap _ref`

Comment: Try with replace this return snapshot.val(); with return { ... results[snapshot] }

Comment: same result as in picture. nothing renders

Comment: Have you put return { ... results[snapshot] }  in map ?

Comment: yes like this `const data = Object.keys(results).map((snapshot) => {
            console.log('snap', snapshot);
            return {...results[snapshot]};
          });`

Comment: what are you getting in console.log('snap', snapshot); ?

Comment: [Fri Feb 05 2021 18:14:08.125]  LOG      snap _snapshot
[Fri Feb 05 2021 18:14:08.131]  LOG      snap _ref

Comment: You are almost at the solution try to debug your app and check the values you are getting and you are accessing it in UI...

Comment: I tried but i'm not getting data in snapshot in Object.keys.map function

Comment: issue is with object.keys as if i do this `console.log('snap', Object.keys(results));` 
i'm getting `_snapshot` and `_ref` in console rather than data

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working example on useEffect to fetch data and display cards based on the data.

Expo => https://snack.expo.io/DYrvw6hOn

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';



export default function App() 
{


  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  const sampleData = [{id:0, title:"One"}, {id:1, title: "Two"}]

  useEffect(() =>
  {

    setTimeout(() => 
    {
      setData(sampleData)

    }, 3000)

  }, [])

  const card = data.length > 0 
  ? data.map(item =>
  {
    return <Card style = {styles.cardStyle}>
        <Text>{item.id} - {item.title}</Text>
      </Card>
  })
  
      : <Text>Loading...</Text>



  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      
      {card}
      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: 
  {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  cardStyle:
  {
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    padding: 20,
    margin: 20
  }
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a state to make the component updates when you get the data you desire. Your code code should be like this:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
export default function New() {
const [data, setData] = useState([])

const getData = async () => {
 const donorsData = [];
database()
  .ref('users')
  .orderByChild('isDonor')
  .equalTo(true)
  .once('value')
  .then((results) => {
    results.forEach((snapshot) => {
      // console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
      //   console.log(snapshot.val());
      donorsData.push(snapshot.val());
    });
    //   console.log('aft', donorsData);
  });
setData(donorsData)
}
useEffect(()=>{
 getData()
},[])
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {data.lenght>0 && data.map((v, i) => {
        return (
          <View
            key={v.uid}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              padding: 10,
              margin: 5,
              borderRadius: 10,
            }}>
            <Text>{v.name}</Text>
            <Text>{v.email}</Text>
            <Image source={{uri: v.photo}} style={{height: 150, flex: 1}} />
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. i have tried using `useState and useEffect` already it didn't work. now i tried by copy pasting ur code didn't work this time too